# Local Certificate Store on Server

Tags: node.js, certificate

might be a dumb question but been tasked with ensuring that a root certificates are in the local certificate store on our server. I have a node server that is hosting an application but I am a bit lost on where to find this local certificate store.

I am able to find it on my local machine following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in, but can't really follow the same process on the server.

Feel like I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here.

Comment: for SSL key and cert ?

Comment: For the node server that is hosting our application I am using a self signed certificate. But that server makes a request to another outside application who has informed me that I would need to ensure that I have a this certain certificate in the local certificate store on our server as they are switching certificate authorities. Lost on where I can find this "local certificate store" on the server though.